# Google Analytics for React Native iOS app using Firebase JavaScript SDK?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I built a React Native iOS app with the Firebase JavaScript SDK. Currently, my Firebase Analytics Dashboard has no data. Can I add Google Analytics to my iOS app using the JS SDK? If so, how?

I am unable to find any information on how to add analytics to React Native iOS apps ***that specifically use the Firebase JavaScript SDK***. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that Firebase config in your code contains `measurementId`.
2. If not, enable it in the project settings and update the config
3. Add the Analytics SDK and initialize it

See [Add the Analytics SDK to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web#add-sdk) for details

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this does not work. I set up the analytics according to the instructions, and do have the measurementId in my config, however the issue is that no data is being recorded.